# Finding text between two words in string in c#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have file which contain messages.Message Start with "A1" and ends with Z1.

below is file content

A1 s=10 y=10 z=120 Z1 VV CCZ

A1 55 77 88 99 Z1 qq  KK A1

uuu Z1 A1 LL KK ZZ  Z1 SS

now you can see message are split in multiple Line.i need to extract all message from file by reading .txt file line by line.

Output will be list of string messages

A1 s=10 y=10 z=120 Z1

A1 55 77 88 99 Z1

A1 uuu Z1

A1 LL KK ZZ  Z1

solution

public void ProcessFile()
        {

```
        string _startingWord = "A1";
        string _endingWord = "Z1";
        bool _waitForlastWord = false;

        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =new System.IO.StreamReader(@"G:\CS Session\Test.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var message = line.Split(' ').ToList();
            if (message.Count(x => x == _startingWord) > 0 || message.Count(x => x == _endingWord) > 0 || _waitForlastWord)
            {

               bool startingFound = false;
               if (_waitForlastWord)
                {
                    startingFound = true;
                }


               foreach (var wrd in message)
               {
                   if (!startingFound)
                   {
                       if (wrd == _startingWord)
                       {
                           startingFound = true;
                       }
                   }

                   if (startingFound)
                   {
                       msg.Append(" " + wrd);

                       if (wrd == _endingWord)
                       {
                           startingFound = false;


                           Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
                           msg = new StringBuilder();
                       }
                   }
               }
               if (! (msg.ToString()==string.Empty))
               {
                   _waitForlastWord = true;
               }
            }



        }

        file.Close();


        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/  We're not here to just write code for you.  Please demonstrate that you've actually attempted to do this, and we might be able to help you figure out what's not working.

Comment: I have edited my question with solution please have look.i need better solution

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this using the `string.IndexOf` method, which finds the position within the string for the keyword you search for.

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    int start = line.IndexOf("A1");
    int end = line.LastIndexOf("Z1") + 2; // add length of keyword.
    if (end > start) 
    {
        int length = end - start; // get the length between the A1 and Z1 positons.
        var result = line.Substring(start, length);
        msg.AppendLine(result);
    }                
}
```

EDIT: Missed that the start/end could span over two lines, which brings this other solution

```
// process all lines first, flatten structure.
string startingWord = "A1";
string endingWord = "Z1";
var contents = File.ReadAllText("path\to\somefile.txt").Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
var result = contents.Split(new string[] { startingWord }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

foreach (var line in result)
{
    int position = line.LastIndexOf(endingWord);
    if (position > -1)
    {
        int end = position + endingWord.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", startingWord, line.Substring(0, end));
    }
}
```

Use `File.ReadAllText` to read the whole file into a single string and `Replace` all occurences of `Environment.NewLine` (\r\n). Then split the string with the starting keyword (A1), which turns it into an array with the given results. Since we split by the keyword, we need to readd that at some point to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching with a regular expression is helpful here: A1(.*?)Z1 - Lazily match a string of characters starting with A1 and ending in Z1 with any amount of characters in between.

```
  var regExp = new Regex("A1(.*?)Z1");

  foreach(var match in regExp.Matches(File.ReadAllText("test.txt")
                       .Replace("\r\n", " ")))
  {
      Console.WriteLine(match);
  }
```

It is assumed a new line is a combination of \r\n and replaced with a space to account for the space after the A1 in your expected output